# woocommerce wc_get_product is not fetching all the product of particular category

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I have created dummy product data with fakerpress and many products were created with "future" status, so I updated the post status to "publish". I wanted to retrieve all the product of selected category. Code for it is :

```
    $args = array(
        'limit'    => -1,
        'status'   => 'publish',
        'category' => array('clothing'),
    );

    $products = wc_get_product($args);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r(count($products));
    echo "</pre>";
    exit();
```

It is returning only 8 products but i have 128 product in this category. I also created product with the woo-commerce sample csv file, on doing so, I am getting the product count exactly as it should be. Can anyone please provide me the hint for what needs to be done ? Any kinds of help are appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT:
What I found is,some products are already in publish status and they are not fetched, but if i edit that product and simply update the product without changing any data, it is fetched. What could be the reason of this. Any ideas ?

WP_Query for fetching posts :

```
    $categories = array(1,2,3); // IDs of categories
    $args = array(
        'post_type'             => 'product',
        'post_status'           => 'publish',
        'ignore_sticky_posts'   => 1,
        'posts_per_page'        => -1,

        'tax_query'             => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy'      => 'product_cat',
                'field' => 'term_id', //This is optional, as it defaults to 'term_id'
                'terms'         => implode(',',$categories),
                'operator'      => 'IN' // Possible values are 'IN', 'NOT IN', 'AND'.
            )
        )
    );
   $postProducts = new WP_Query($args);
```

This returns the post data as required but cannot retrieve meta_keys and values associated with product.

Comment: i guess your problem is the count thing, since `$products` is not an array, but an object. i guess `$products->total` will return your desired number. on a side note: i am not too familiar with `wc_get_products()`, i'd rather use standard `WP_Query`. [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) you can find the documentation on `WP_Query` and [here](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query#general) you can find the documentation on `wc_get_products()`

Comment: @honk31 Thanks for your reply. But,$products is an array of object, and count() works perfectly fine. I also tried as you said, but there was problem in loading all the products related attributes. Can you help me to get all the meta_name and meta_value of post_type product ? I have edited the and put wp_query thinking you would probably help. Thanks.

Comment: you updated your above code, but the first one now is wrecked. `WP()` is not a valid function i guess. but that is not the point. as i said, `wc_get_products()` will not return an array, it will return an object. what do you get with your previous function, when yo call `$products->total`? and what do you mean by `meta_name` & `value`? what meta?? plus: in the documentation i linked in my previous comment, wc claims, that their method is more future-proof. plus i saw some build in features in there, that i kinda like. so lets stick to this one here.. and tell me, what you want to archive..

Comment: @honk31 I want to get post.*,postmeta.*, and some selected columns of terms with WP_Query.

Comment: and what do you get, when you do `echo "<pre>", print_r($products->total), "</pre>";` on your first example..?

Comment: @honk31 it is still 8. I got the reason behind it. wc_get_product($args), always fetch products which have product_type=>array('simple','variable','external','grouped') and on creating products with fakerpress it doesn't created taxonomy product_type and relate with term, therefore it was not coming.
What about with WP_Query() ?

Comment: ah, ok. makes sense. that might work with with WP_Query, but honestly.. in your state of progress, you are dealing with fake content.. dont rely on that, create some real products so you wont have these type of issues.. as stated before, the `wc_get_products()` doesnt look too bad, now that i looked at it.. its more like fakerpress is doing it wrong, not wc.. [here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/importing-woocommerce-sample-data/) is what you want

Comment: @honk31 Thank you for all you help. I already implemented wc_get_products() and i got that issue while testing. Now I made my Q&A understand the issue. Its okay now.